# How to get current comment for selected documents with the same id?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I wanted to get the current comment for the document that selected. But the problem is. In my tables **comments** I have the same `document_id`. I just wanted to get the comment for the selected documents.

I'm thinking should I make my `document_id` unique? For me able to get the comment for one document. Still don't have idea how can I retrieve the comment for selected documents.

[image: DB]

**DocumentController**:

This is where I retrieve the document selected also the comment. As you can see here I retrieve the document that selected in my **sent_document_user** table with **comments** table. But when I tried to retrieve the comments based on selected documents. It takes all the comment in my database. I don't know where part I'm getting the error.

```
public function readSentDocuments($id)
{

    $documentLists = DB::table('sent_document_user')->select('documents.title', 'categories.category_type', 'documents.content', 'documents.id')
    ->join('documents', 'documents.id', '=', 'sent_document_user.document_id')
    ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'documents.category_id')->first();

    $commentLists = DB::table('comments')
    ->select('comments.comment_content', 'users.username', 'comments.id')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'comments.commentBy')->get();

    return view ('document.readSent')->with('documentLists', $documentLists)->with('commentLists', $commentLists);

}
```

This is all the list document where the user has an option to choose.

```
public function showSentDocuments()
{

    $documentSent = DB::table('receive_document_user')->select('documents.title', 'documents.content', 'categories.category_type', 'users.username', 'receive_document_user.dateReceived', 'documents.id')
        //Table name     //PK                  //FK
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'receive_document_user.user_id')
        ->join('documents', 'documents.id', '=', 'receive_document_user.document_id')
        ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'documents.category_id')
        ->where('sender_id', '=', Auth::id())->get();

    return view ('document.sent')->with('documentSent', $documentSent);
}
```

**CommentController**

This is where saving or inserting of comments happen.

```
class CommentController extends Controller
{

public function postComments(Request $request, Document $id)
{

    $this->validate($request,
    [
        'comment' => 'required',
    ]);



    $commentObject = new Comment();

    $user = Auth::user();

    $commentObject->comment = $request->comment;
    $commentObject->sender_id = $user->id;

        //Obtaining the instance of relationship. The save method will automatically add the appropriate comment_id and sender_id value to the new Comment model.
    $id->comments()->save($commentObject);


    return redirect()->back();
}
}
```

**View**

```
<div class = "col-md-6">

    <form class = "form-vertical">

        <div class = "form-group">

            <div class="panel panel-default">

                <div class="panel-heading">Comments</div>

                @foreach ($commentLists as $list)
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p>{{ $list->comment }}</p>
                        <strong>Comment by:</strong>
                        <p>{{ $list->username }}</p>
                        <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary">Reply</button>
                    </div>
                @endforeach

            </div>       

        </div>

    </form>

</div>
```

**Models**

Comment

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $tables = 'comments';

    protected $fillable =
    [
        'comment_content',
    ];


    public function documents()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Document');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Comment');
    }
}
```

Document

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Document extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'documents';

    protected $fillable = 
    [
        'title',
        'content',
        'category_id',
    ];


    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comment');
    }
}
```

User

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract
{
    use Authenticatable;

    public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comment');
}
}
```

**Migration**

documents

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('documents', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('content');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

users

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('middle_name');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('address');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('remember_token');

        $table->integer('role_permission_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('role_permission_id')->references('id')->on('roles_permissions_dt')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: you are having multiple comments but you want to get the latest one only?

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim Yes I'm having multiple comments for the current document and I wanted to get only the comment for current document. But my problem is I have same document_id.

Comment: So what identifies the `selected document` if it is not the `doument_id`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Still thinking how can I solve this problem

Comment: I dont think I proerly undestand the problem you describe! Can you have another try at explaining

Comment: Make it unique so there can only be 1 comment on a document. Or make it a column to the documents table. 
If you want the newest comment by using laravel, add: `->orderBy('comments.created_at', 'desc')->take(1)`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I elaborate my post. Please see.

Comment: Try this `->where('document_id', '=', $documentLists->id)->get();`

Comment: @user2468160 I wanted the user can have multiple comments for the document. How can I make this unique? What part of column should I unique?

Comment: @Maraboc I tried your solution but still I retrieve all the comments.

Comment: do you want to fetch all comments related to the selected document or the latest comment of the selected document?

Comment: @ishadif Yes I want to fetch all the related comments based on the selected document. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: Does your selected document has unique id ? I mean, each document must be having an unique id. Right ?

Comment: What does *current comment* mean?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that

1. You are having unique id for each document in your document
   Model. i.e. the primary key for the Documents Table.
2. You are having an unique id for each user in your User Model. i.e.
   the primary key for the Users Table.

So, your Models would have following methods to define relationship between them along with your other methods and attributes.

**Document Model:**

```
public function Comments(){
    return $this->hasMany('path_to_your_Comment_Model/Comment');
}
```

**User Model:**

```
//For using in first Approach Below
public function Comments($document_id){
    return $this->hasMany('path_to_your_Comment_Model/Comment')
                ->where('document_id',$document_id);
}
//For using in second Approach Below
public function Comments(){
    return $this->hasMany('path_to_your_Comment_Model/Comment');
}
```

**Comment Model:**

```
public function User(){
    return $this->belongsTo('path_to_your_User_Model/User');
}

public function Document(){
    return $this->belongsTo('path_to_your_Document_Model/Document');
}
```

Now to retrieve the Comments from the comments table for Document identified by `document_id` and the User identified by `user_id`, you can use the following code in your controller.

**First Approach:**

```
public function getComments(Request $request){
    $document_id = $request->document_id;//Retrieving document_id of selected document  
    $comments = Auth::User->user()->Comments($document_id)->get();
    // Your code to handle retrieved comments
}
```

**Second Approach:**

```
public function getComments(Request $request){
    $document_id = $request->document_id;//Retrieving document_id of selected document  

    $comments = Auth::User->user()->whereHas('comments',function($query) use($document_id){
                $query->where('document_id',$document_id);
                })
                ->get();
    // Your code to handle retrieved comments
}
```

Comment: In place of `document_id` in above example you have to use the primary key of your documents table

Comment: I'm gonna try your solution now. Thanks for this bro. I'll update you.

Comment: I would suggest to use first approach as I think it is more clean.

Comment: While trying your solutions. I'll updated my post so you can have idea please see :)

Comment: Could you also update your question with document and user table structure. Did you try my solution ? any error ?

Comment: what purpose `receive_document_user` table and `sent_document_user` table provides

Comment: I'll updated my post. I'm still trying now your solution. Still fetching all the comments even it has different `document_id`. The `receive_document_user` this is where the current user retrieve all the documents that sent to him/her. The `sent_document_user` this is where all the sended documents created by users.

Comment: As you can see in my `readSentDocuments` I already included all the comments the user has an option to add a comment.

Comment: Still thinking how can I add your solution in the same controller. How can I make a unique id for each document?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120263/discussion-between-jaysingkar-and-francisunoxx).

Comment: did you find the cause of hidden input ?

Comment: No still didn't find a solution for the hidden input.

Comment: ohh.. Could you do some other change in the form to check if the form is updating

Answer (score 1):

if you want to fetch all the related comments based on the selected document, you can leverage eloquent by defining your document model and comment model. I assume that relationship will be

```
//this is in your document model
public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

so if you want to fetch all comments for some specific document :

```
//this is in your controller
$document = Document::find($id);
$document->comments()->get(); //getching all comments
//or
$document->comments; //either will work
```

then, you will loop that collection in your view.

Comment: I think you forgot to include the class in the top of your file. Like: `use Name\Space\Of\Comment`.

Comment: @ThomasVanderVeen What's the use of `Comment::class`? I just wanted to get the current comment for the selected documents.

Comment: just import your `comment` model namespace at the very top. if you want to get the latest one comment of the selected document you can try `$document->comments()->latest()->first()` . it will give one comment object instead of a collection of comments

Comment: I already imported the `comment` model at the top but it says. `Class App\Models\Document does not exist`

Comment: in your controller?

Answer (score 0):

@Francisunoxx My English not good but try to give you reference. you can filter by sender_id
Assuming that `sender_id` same as `user_id`
in `app/User.php`

```
// user has many comments
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CommentsTable','by_user_id');
    }
```

then in `app/Http/Controllers/UserController.php`

```
 public function profile(Request $request, $id) 
  {
    $data['user'] = User::find($id);//find exist user_id

    $data['latest_comments'] = $data['user'] -> comments -> take(5);
    return view('admin.profile', $data);
  }
```

View for profile in `resources/views/admin/profile.blade.php`

```
       @foreach($latest_comments as $cmt)
            <p>{{ $cmt->comment_field }}</p>                
        @endforeach
```

i hope can help